# iOS - save data so that it is easily accessible outside of the app

Tags: ios, iphone, file, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to save a file (to be exact, a .csv) somewhere outside the application sandbox? From what I've read it seems like it is only possible to save files inside the sandbox.

Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way, maybe I don't really need to save it outside the sandbox. What I actually need to do is:

Allow the user to save the file, so that he can use it in other applications (for example email client), and it would be best if the file would stay on his device after he deleted the app. The location of the saved file doesn't really matter, it could be chosen by user with some file picker or hard-coded. Is there any way to achieve this?

I'm using xamarin.forms so solution easy to implement in xamarin.forms would be much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot save files outside the sandbox (I know what you mean). You probably have to store it online. Look into iCloud/iDrive maybe you can save it there.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I've read it seems like it is only possible to save files inside the sandbox.

That is the general idea. You don't just have access to the filesystem on iOS. You could work around this by maybe saving it to iCloud or Dropbox, etc. depending on your use-case but basically you can't just save it somewhere common. Normally, you would then implement the 'share' functionality. What happens then is that iOS copies the file into the other apps' sandbox so it can work with it.